# Resend the same file simultaneously with netcat in listening mode

Tags: netcat

I want to set up netcat in listening mode so that many clients can connect and they all receive the same file.  The clients should be able to connect simultaneously...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ nc --listen --keep-open --send-only --exec "/usr/bin/cat /path/to/myfile" 0.0.0.0 5800
$ nc 127.0.0.1 5800 > recvfile
```

Comment: This command sends the file only once. I'm using Ncat: Version 6.25 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )

Comment: You're right. You can use the `--exec` option instead.